# How do i enable to prompt password for default SSH user for sudo commands

Tags: linux, ssh

I have centos 7.3 machine on AWS. The default ssh user is 'centos' However when i run any command with sudo for this user it doesn't ask for password. So how do i make it to prompt for password while doing sudo for default ssh user.I even tried adding `Defaults rootpw` in `/etc/sudoers` file

Note: When i create a new user and give sudo access to it, it always asks password while running sudo command for this new user. Its just doesnot work for default user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won’t be prompted for a password when either the configuration file `/etc/sudoers` or any of the the drop in configuration snippets in `etc/sudoers.d/` contain  lines similar to

```
centos  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Which allows only your user account to execute commands without a password prompt or a line similar to

```
%sudo  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Which allows all members of the group named sudo that privilege and your user centos is a member of that group.

Either remove the centos user from that group or edit the configuration and remove the `NOPASSWD:` directive.

Comment: Isn't removing the `NOPASSWD:` directive the only method that answers the question?

Comment: `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users` is 'readonly'. Is it ok if i change the permission?
 It has an entry `centos ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Comment: It's read-only on purpose. You're supposed to use `visudo` to edit it. `visudo` validates the edit before commiting it, avoiding  syntax errors that could lock you out of root access.

Comment: @EsaJokinen if the permissions are assigned to group and you remove all members of said then removing the :NOPASSWD is not needed

Comment: @HBruijn: I interpret "and give sudo access to it" as adding the user to the `sudo` group. Maybe that's why I understood this a bit differently. :)